# How can I get the index path.row of first UITableView in the Second UITableView using Swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, nsindexpath

I have two `UITableView`s. The first `UITableView` contains an array of data, and the second is empty. How can I get the index path of the first table to use it in the second table to view different data? This is an example of what I want to do in the second table:

This is in the second table and like this function where I want to get the `indexPath.row` of first table.

```
  func loadData() {

      if indexPath.row == 0 { // (of first table)

      // add code

      } else if indexPath.row == 1 { // (of first table)

       // add code

     }
 }
```

Comment: Please elaborate, your question is not clear, what is meant by indexpath of first table into second??

Comment: I want to get the index for the tapped row of first table view to use it in the function below of second tableview.

Comment: You can set a tag value for each indexPath and then on tapping those rows these tags can be retrieved and passed on to the loadData() to load corresponding value or set of values. Tag value should be a unique value.

Comment: you need to store a first table view index into a variable and pass that variable into second view controller as property then you can easily do that.every time first table row selected you update this variable value and once you go to next viewcontroller pass this value.

Comment: Would you please write the code in answer Because I'am new in Swift . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Implement **`didSelectRowAt`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    let selctedIndex = indexPath.row
    self.setIndexToSecondTableView(selctedIndex) //Create your function to get selected index of first table view
}
```

Comment: @Zaid Mustafa Please see answer above and let me know if you need any other clarification

Comment: What do you mean with (Create your function to get selected index of first table view) can you please write a complete code to get index.

Comment: @ Zaid Mustafa Would be better if you explain you requirement in detail. I can provide you complete code but the thing is what i got from your Question is I answered. Explain like you have Screen A and Screen B or You have Two UItableview in a Single Screen like this.

Comment: I will add a new question with screenshots of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hope You get solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            if tableView.isEqual(firstTableView) {
               self.updateScecondTableView(index: IndexPath.row) //make a function to retrieve selected index from first table view
            } else {
                // acode
            }
        }

func updateScecondTableView(index:NSIndexPath)  {
        switch index.row {
        case 0:
            // add a code
            break

        default:
            // add a code
            break
        }
    }
```